# How to uninstall Libre Office 6.2?

Tags: software-installation, apps

I installed Libre Office 6.2, then it would not launch (the icon appeared in the dock, then disappeared a few seconds later). I then reinstalled Libre Office 6.1 and that works fine, but I can't see how to remove 6.2. The sudo apt remove libreoffice 6.2 does not work, there is no right-click to uninstall in the app list. Any idea? 
Thanks!
Fred

Comment: in which way did you install 6.2 (snap, flatpak etc.)?

Comment: Good question :) I think it was Flathub, a link given at the end of the piece here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/02/libreoffice-6-2-features

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fred, welcome back!

I did not install LibreOffice via Flatpak, however, I do have *some* experience with Flatpak.

Here is the online manual regarding the Flatpak [command](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html).

The **TLDR** *CliffsNotes* version boils down to this.
1. Go to Applications -> Terminal (Win+T)
2. Type: `flatpak list --app --show-details`
3. You should see a LibreOffice line with the following information: 6.2     stable x86_64 flathub system       org.libreoffice.LibreOffice...
4. It is that **last** part that we care about.  The uninstall command would be:
5. Type: `flatpak uninstall org.libreoffice.LibreOffice`
6. After the uninstall is successful, press Cont+D to exit the Terminal.

Also try executing `sudo snap remove libreoffice` if the above process don't work.

I hope that helps!  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I can't have installed it with Flapak after all, your first command line gives me a 'command flatpak not found' ...

Comment: Hi again, I found the simple command that did it: sudo snap remove libreoffice